# Workbench not allowing SOQL or DML

Tags: salesforcedx, workbench

It is continuously rerouting to the login page and not allowing SOQL or DML. The error is: `UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379`

Comment: Workbench is a free service and there is no sla for it to work. You can host workbench on heroku or on ec2 https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench